# ERROR TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" al correr app en node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Presento el siguiente error

**TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"**

Al intentar correr mi aplicacion en node.js

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es2019",
    },
    "files": [
        "app.ts",
    ]
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "menuDigital-apis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.13.4",
    "babel-node": "^0.0.1-security",
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "catchify": "^2.6.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dev": "^0.1.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.10",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "pg": "^8.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.9.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node ./app.ts --experimental-modules"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-watch": "^2.0.7",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-cmd": "^3.0.0",
    "node-ssh": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "printWidth": 100,
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "endOfLine": "lf"
  },
  "author": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo remueve **"type":"module"** de la configuración de tu package.json, espero esto te funcione.